# Order By Case in SQL Server issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have below sql server query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE (group, 'DEFAULT') AS name
FROM        groups
order by 
   case 
     when group = 'DEFAULT' 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 2 
   END, group
```

What I want to obtain is a column with group values not repeated and the 'DEFAULT' one at the first position of the result and then the rest.

For example I want to obtain:

```
NAME
----

DEFAULT
GROUP1
GROUP2
GROUP3
```

and so on.

Of course, from above query I get below error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: The example seems incomplete,  e.g. are you left joining groups to some other table?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `COALESCE (group, 'DEFAULT')` instead of `group` in the CASE. If this doesn't work, take the `CASE` into the `SELECT` List.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select COALESCE ([group], 'DEFAULT') AS name
From
(
    SELECT Distinct *
    FROM groups
)as A
order by 
   (case 
     when [group] = 'DEFAULT' 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 2 
   END), 
   [group]
```

Comment: This does not work if I have more than one column with different values.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1624552/user1624552 : Could you please elaborate little bit regarding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Null` will be before other strings after sorting, so even the most simple query

```
SELECT DISTINCT [group], COALESCE ([group], 'DEFAULT') AS name
FROM [groups] order by [group]
```

should work for you. Note that `group` must be in distinct select clause (this is basically what error tells you.

**Edit:**

If you really don't want one more column in result, you can use subquery select, something like:

```
select COALESCE(bname, 'DEFAULT') as name FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [group] as bname FROM [groups]) t 
ORDER by bname;
```

Comment: But I do not want an extra column (group) in the result, I only want to obtain one column, in this case, name.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you may want like this

```
Select COALESCE ([group], 'DEFAULT') AS name
From
(
    SELECT Distinct [group]
    FROM groups
)as A
order by 
   (case 
     when [group] = 'DEFAULT' 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 2 
   END), 
   [group]
```